# theta role, infinitival phrase

Tags: syntax

What is the motivation to assume an unpronounced Pro when there is infinitival phrase in the context of phrase structure grammar?

Eg. I hope to hit the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified example from the Wikipedia page on PRO:

> John_i promised Bill [CP [TP PRO_i to control the situation]]

> John convinced Bill_j [CP [TP PRO_j to control the situation]]

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRO_%28linguistics%29)

There's something that was proposed to be there in order to have a subject for the embedded TP, which corefers to a particular argument in the main clause when these (control) verbs are used. The relevance theta-roles is just the semantic side of things-- although most semanticists today agree that theta-roles do not exist, in favor of syntactic event structures that align with semantic event information. But even then, there should be something there to have a complete the event structure, or for case reasons.

Comment: Thank you for this illustration. This answer is helpful to me!  And I am wondering why most semanticists today agree that theta-roles do not exist.  Could you please tell me more details so that I can know more about it? Thank you so much for your explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure I would be able to explain it too well (and I don't want to give you misinformation) but you may possibly find this talk helpful and interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_bjHrMunWo. :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this link！